# Two pointers different information stored

Tags: c++, pointers

Is it true that having:

```
int* p = new int;
```

and:

```
int* p1 = new int[5]();
```

in case of p1 there will be extra info stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there might be.

I recommend you read the following to items from C++-faq :

- [How does the compiler know there are n objects to be destructed using delete[] ?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.14)
- [How do compilers use "over-allocation" to remember the number of elements in an allocated array ?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/compiler-dependencies.html#faq-38.7)

A relevant quote extracted from the first link :

> The run-time system stores the number
>   of objects, n, somewhere where it can
>   be retrieved if you only know the
>   pointer, p. There are two popular
>   techniques that do this. [...]
>
> - Over-allocate the array and put n just to the left of the first Fred object.
> - Use an associative array with p as the key and n as the value

Answer (score 3):

[This C++-FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.14) entry should answer your question.